# WordPress for Linux Web App is lost after enabling WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE

Tags: wordpress, containers, azure-web-app-service

I installed Wordpress for Linux as an Azure WebApp. I set it up and installed a few plugins only to find out later that they were gone. A little investigation revealed that the storage in the container doesn't persist across container restart and hence why my plugins were not persisted. I then enabled `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE`, but now my site shows up with the empty Web App Template:

> Your App Service app is up and running

It looks like turning the App Service Storage maps the Web Server to Azure Storage and my container is now "useless". How do I retain files and have Wordpress running at the same time? I would imagine that Wordpress is a little useless without being able to persist storage...

Comment: You enabled `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` to true or false?

Comment: I went through the wizard on the Add New Website. I selected Wordpress for Linux. By default the setting was `false`. I configured Wordpress, the issue arose, so I enabled it to `true` and my website is now gone

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is out of date.if you are using Wordpress for Linux as an Azure WebApp, Below readme.md maybe help.
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-quickstart-docker-images/tree/master/wordpress-alpine-php/0.4